# c# в string записан двоичный код.как перевести его в текст?

Tags: c#, строки

Есть метод который возвращает string , в строку записан двоичный код.
Как преобразовать этот "текстовый" двоичный код в текст?

Comment: если двоичный код не зашифрован и при этом представляет некий текст то он сам этим текстом и является. так что поясните что вы имеете ввиду под "двоичным кодом"

Comment: Вот именно, не ясно, что именно содержится в "двоичном" коде. Есть [аналогичный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297468/get-string-value-from-a-byte-string) на English SO, но там тоже угадайка.

Comment: Посмотри тут, возможно поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436398/convert-a-binary-string-representation-to-a-byte-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string bitStr = "010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101";
var stringArray = Enumerable.Range(0, bitStr.Length / 8).Select(i => Convert.ToByte(bitStr.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stringArray);
```